# How to deal with the file size changing between a stat and a subsequent mmap?

Tags: c, linux, file, posix, mmap

To determine the size for an `mmap` call I use `stat`, and pass the acquired size as the respective length of the mapping to create. In case the file size changes between the calls my understanding is that it will either only map part of the file or in case of shrinking I won't have the actual size of the mapping to refer to and get `SIGBUS` on accessing a range that is not part of the underlying object.

How to cleanly handle this case?

Comment: How do you want to handle it if the file size changes after the mmap?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that I'm using mmap with PROT_READ and MAP_PRIVATE  and my impression is that writes external to the mmap-calling process will not affect the mapping...? Is that incorrect?

Comment: No - writes to the file even after the mmap() call may be visible inside your process. PROT_READ just means your process isn't allowed to write to the memory; MAP_PRIVATE means any writes your process does won't be reflected in the file; it does not guarantee that writes to the file won't affect your process (though this may be the case in some implementations).

Comment: Thanks, I see I have missed the following line in POSIX: "It is unspecified whether modifications to the underlying object done after the MAP_PRIVATE mapping is established are visible through the MAP_PRIVATE mapping".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't protect against this sort of thing in general. If the file could have changed length (presumably due to some external process) between the `stat()` and the `mmap()`, why can't it change length after the `mmap()`? To put this another way (detailed explanation below), what you are asking for is not *enough* to protect you from an adversary.

If you really want to check the mapping is still valid after `mmap` (i.e. the file has not got shorter) you could (ab)use `remap_file_pages` on linux (untested); however, for the reasons set out that won't help you if someone truncates it soon after.

See also this warning from the manpage:

> The effect of changing the size of the underlying file of a mapping on the pages that correspond to added or removed regions of the file is unspecified.

You will need some form of file locking in order to protect yourself. As you say in the comments you are dealing with an adversary who won't respect advisory locking, then unless you use the (rare) [mandatory locking](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt).

I believe the only ways to be completely safe here are:

- Do not use `mmap`
- Change the permissions of the file or copy the file such that the adversary cannot access it / the copy.

---

To further illustrate the problem of an attacker changing the length of the file after you `mmap`, consider the test program below. This creates a file of length `LONGFILE`, opens it, and then either:

- simulates an adversary truncating it, then `mmap`'s it; or
- `mmap`'s it, then simulates an adversary truncating it

In *both* instances, a segmentation fault is created. So if, as you say, you are concerned that your adversary may be able to change the length of the file after you have opened it, then you simply shouldn't be `mmap`'ing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


/*
  void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags,
       int fd, off_t offset);
  int munmap(void *addr, size_t length);
*/

#undef TRUNCATE_BEFORE_MMAP
#define TRUNCATE_AFTER_MMAP
char *testfile = "/tmp/mmaptest";
#define SHORTFILE 10
#define LONGFILE 81920


int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int fd;
  int sum;
  size_t size = LONGFILE;
  int i;
  char *buf;

  if ((fd = open (testfile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0777)) < 0)
    {
      perror ("initial open");
      exit (1);
    }
  close (fd);
  if (truncate (testfile, LONGFILE) < 0)
    {
      perror ("truncate");
      exit (1);
    }

  if ((fd = open ("/etc/services", O_RDONLY)) < 0)      /* a short file */
    {
      perror ("open");
      exit (1);
    }

#ifdef TRUNCATE_BEFORE_MMAP
  if (truncate (testfile, SHORTFILE) < 0)
    {
      perror ("truncate");
      exit (1);
    }
#endif

  if (MAP_FAILED == (buf = mmap (NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0)))
    {
      perror ("mmap");
      exit (1);
    }

#ifdef TRUNCATE_AFTER_MMAP
  if (truncate (testfile, SHORTFILE) < 0)
    {
      perror ("truncate");
      exit (1);
    }
#endif

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      sum += buf[i];
    }

  if (munmap (buf, size) < 0)
    {
      perror ("munmap");
      exit (1);
    }
  if (close (fd) < 0)
    {
      perror ("close");
      exit (1);
    }
  exit (0);
}
```

Comment: File locking as far as I know is voluntary and requires cooperating processes. I'm thinking of a scenario where the files are controlled by an attacker that can in this way affect the behaviour of the program. See my other comment to why I think process-external writes after the mmap are irrelevant and please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If the files are controlled by an attacker, you are pretty much dead in the water as if the file is truncated even *after* you `mmap`, then you can get a `SEGV`. I've made this clearer and added a code example to demonstrate.

Comment: Also re process external writes and `MAP_PRIVATE`, those won't affect the content of the file, but they affect the length of data mapped. See my test.

Comment: mmap does not necessarily return (void *)0 (the definition of the NULL macro in POSIX), but MAP_FAILED on error. And would a SIGSEGV actually happen with a process-private mapping?

Comment: @nxbit Good catch on the error check - I will fix. I get a `SIGBUS`. You can't guarantee it will actually happen as its UB. On mine it happens 20480 bytes in.

Comment: What is UB? I think SIGBUS is specified to happen on access of a range that is not part of the underlying object as I have mentioned in my original question. POSIX says "References within the address range starting at pa and continuing for len bytes to whole pages following the end of an object shall result in delivery of a SIGBUS signal."

Comment: UB = undefined behaviour. It might or might not work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm asking what you think is undefined behaviour? The SIGBUS happening?

Comment: @nixbit: per the manpage: *The effect of changing the size of the underlying file of a mapping on the pages that correspond to added or removed regions of the file is unspecified.'* - 'unspecified' meaning it may unmap some of them but not others (which is what seems to happen in practice). Accessing an unmapped page will result in SIGBUS/SIGSEGV

Answer (score 0):

mmap is not very easy to use for things that vary in length. If you control all sides of the process, you can use a semaphore to do concurrency control between readers and writers, including having the writer write the correct length into a header field. If you are mapping a file that some arbitrary process can grow or shrink, you may need to use signal handlers to protect yourself from this, not to mention arbitrary changes to the contents.